# Tableau - 2 Custom SQL Queries - One Parameter updates two sheets

Tags: sql-server, performance, tableau-api

I have two different data sets using two different SQL queries. Essentially one data set is day/caller stats rolled up the other set is call data. So each call data set rolls up to get their day/caller data.

I needed to separate these two queries for performance because I needed one extract and one parameterized custom query for the call data. So essentially I will always bring in this month of data and last month for the day/caller data.

What I need to do is create one dashboard, that has the caller and all of their stats aggregated for the time period. Then I need to be able to click a row to prompt all the call data in a different sheet on the same dashboard

I am at the home stretch and need a way to connect these two sheets and update the call data. Right now I only have a parameter for the Unique ID of the callers not time, I bring in all the same days of calls even though it is really not needed. In a perfect world I will click the report caller and my second query will update to the appropriate day range and Unique ID and produce only that callers calls. My problem right now is no matter what I do I cannot create the one sheet to update the second call sheet. I have successfully created a manually functioning report but I need the action to filter to a timer period and the specific caller.

Let me know if you have any feedback. My two issues are creating two separate queries  caller data (225k rows help in export) call data (7 million rows if unfiltered) which needs to be a live connection so when sheet is clicked the parameters will update and those calls will populate. Anything would help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution i can think of is to use an action filter and there is an option below to select the fields to map between the sheets.Choose selected fields instead of all fields and map the id and time between the two data  sources.
Apart from this i dont really get what the issue is.If you need further clarifications please rephrase your questions and provide examples and your data structure.